# Check for all null values in a GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have the following structre

```
id val
1 ...
.
.
2 ...
.
.
3 null
3 null
3 null
4 ...
.
.
```

Basically each id has multiple no. of values. And **an id has either all values as integers or all values as null**

What I want is to perform an aggregate (like AVG) on val group by id. If that id has null values, I want to put 5 there.

#1

```
SELECT id, (CASE SUM(val) WHEN null THEN 5 ELSE AVG(val) END) AS ac FROM tt GROUP BY id
> executes ELSE even for id = 3
```

In CASE, there should be an aggregate function that when done on null values give null.
I checked SUM and MAX like

```
SELECT SUM(val) FROM tt WHERE id = 3
> null
```

and it gives null here but doesn't work in  main statement. I guess it is related to the type of equality and hence tried `WHEN IS NULL` but its a syntax error.

Also, is there some more standard way of indicating group of values as all null rather than using SUM or MAX.

Comment: You want to be using something like: `CASE WHEN SUM(val) IS NULL THEN 5 ELSE AVG(val) END` ... but I would just use `COALESCE()` instead.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this approach was more suitable in my case rather than `coalesce` since I wanted to put `avg` of some other column in the result but check null on val column.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You may include this one also in your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `if` condition :

```
select id, If(sum(val) is null, 5, AVG(val)) as average
FROM tt
group by id
```

check here : https://dbfiddle.uk/Uso9nNTM

Comment: Copy of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The exact problem with your `CASE` expression is that to check for null in MySQL we have to use `IS NULL` rather than equality.  So use this version:

```sql
CASE WHEN SUM(val) IS NULL THEN 5 ELSE AVG(val) END
```

But we might as well just use `COALESCE()` to assign an average of 5 for those `id` groups having all null values.

```sql
SELECT id, COALESCE(AVG(val), 5) AS avg_val
FROM tt
GROUP BY id;
```

Note that the `AVG()` function by default ignores nulls.  Therefore, the expression `AVG(val)` would only be null if *every* record in an `id` group were having null for `val`.